How to improve dielectric function calculated using Independent particle approximation VASP?
I am trying to reproduce a paper linked below. First i did scf calculation adding external electric field of 0.3V/A and than i use WAVECAR generated from there to compute frequency dependent dielectric function using LOPTICS=TRUE. INCAR is shown below, However my results are different from paper. Am i doing some mistakes in calculation or how can i improve the results?. I tried ALGO=CHI also but the calculation did not complete even after 4-5 days. Please help me.
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/apl/article/122/16/162403/2882846/Electrical-tuning-of-robust-layered.
ALGO = Exact
NBANDS  = 64
LOPTICS = .TRUE.
CSHIFT = 0.400
NEDOS = 2000
LPEAD = .TRUE.
results from paper

my result at E=0.3V/A for xy component. There is a sign difference also in my calculations.


You are being very unclear of what it is you have tried to do. The dielectric function is notoriously difficult to compute; one way is to calculate with electron-phonon coupling, and another way is to apply renormalisation via GW. Both ways are extremely computationally intensive, and it does not seem like you have tried either.

The paper uses spin-polarised DFT followed by TDDFT to compute the dielectric function, have you tried that? Also note that they don't use VASP for this, they use Exciting (e.g. http://exciting.wikidot.com/neon-moke-effect).

yes Phil, They used exciting code in case of heterostructure but for Cr2CCl2 they said "Generally, the signal of MOKE is associated with the off diagonal components of the optical conductivity tensors. Its frequency dependent dielectric function has been calculated as shown in Fig. 3(g). Kindly have a look at this text in paper. Did I interpreted it wrongly?

@ naturallyInconsistent I follow the vasp tutorial https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Dielectric_properties_of_SiC for frequency dependent dielectric function calculation using LOPTICS TRUE. As in the paper they calculated it for different electric field I did it for E=0.3 V/A  and plotted function is for xy component. If my question is still unclear i can send the INCAR file.

Could you please share any link how can i do this type of calculation.
